# CSS: Align image right bottom of a div filled with text

Tags: html, css

I'm making myself a website but I'm a little stuck on an issue I am having.

Inside a div I have a block of text with variable height.
At the right side of the text I want to position an image width a variable width & height. It has to be aligned to the bottom
Above the image may not come any text.

It needs to be like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqpttrvefrvci52/example.jpg

Here is the code I'm currently having:

HTML:

```
<div id="section">
   <div id="image">
      <img src="example.jpg" alt="image"/>
   </div>
   <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam congue, nisl et facilisis commodo, sem tortor suscipit massa, nec rutrum eros nunc et orci.
   Maecenas nibh erat, pulvinar sed aliquam at, malesuada nec nibh.Curabitur fringilla justo odio. Aenean tristique consequat lorem vel tincidunt.
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#section {
    position: relative;
}
#image {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: o;
    right: 0;
}
```

With this code the image is aligned to the bottom right corner of the div, but the height of the div is lower then the height of the image.
Also the text just goes through the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a couple of things to fix this.

1) add padding-right to the section so it does not overlap with the image.

```
#section {
    position: relative;
    padding-right:<at least image width so the text doesn't overlap>
}
```

2) when you add a div and float in it, the float remove the image from the flow of the document so you need to add another internal div with the same height or make the height of the div the same height as your image or just add a floater div..

```
<div id="image">
   <img src="example.jpg" alt="image"/>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/zV3wm/

Comment: but didn't the question state the image width was variable?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a way with variable image widths and text amounts, but it requires some duplication in the markup.

The gist is that you right-float a hidden version of the image, and then use overflow:hidden so that the paragraph against the float doesn't flow under it. Then, we use absolute positioning to place the non-hidden version of the image at the bottom of the container.

I have prepared a mockup at http://jsfiddle.net/UmGNZ/ (I have given the hidden image partial opacity, so you can see where it's being added to the document), but for a pseudo-HTML example:

```
<container with position:relative>
    <right-float>
        <hidden img tag with opacity: 0 />
        <actual img tag with absolute positioning, bottom: 0, right: 0 />
    </right-float>
    <p with overflow:hidden (or auto) />
</container>
```

You could also try a pure CSS solution using CSS tables if you don't have to support IE7, but otherwise this should work down to IE6 if you use visibility:hidden in favour of opacity, and add a zoom:1 to the paragraph style.

Answer (score 0):

This idea which allows a flexible image size: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/F3zZU/4/

```
.cell {display:table-cell;}

#section {
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
}
#image {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

<div id="section">
   <div class="cell">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam congue, nisl et facilisis commodo, sem tortor suscipit massa, nec rutrum eros nunc et orci.Maecenas nibh erat, pulvinar sed aliquam at, malesuada nec nibh.Curabitur fringilla justo odio. Aenean tristique consequat lorem vel tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="image" class="cell">
        <img src="http://placeimg.com/120/80/any" alt="image"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont thing I am correct but you can achieve that by float right and margin-top.

```
#img {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -140px;
}
```

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/wrujx/

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution is to use a little bit of jQuery (JavaScript) and let each part do its job keeping it as simple as possible. Here's what you'd have:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <p>yourtexthere</p>
    <img src="whatever.jpg"/>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{

    width:600px;
    border:1px solid #000000;

}

p{

    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;

}

img{

    vertical-align:bottom;

}
```

**jQuery**

```
var parentWidth = $('#wrapper').width()
var imgWidth = $('img').width()
$('p').width((parentWidth - imgWidth) - 20)
```

And [there you go](http://jsfiddle.net/UmGNZ/4/) plain and simple without extra tags and messy positioning.